# How do I export a .mov with openshot?

Tags: openshot

I recorded my desktop with [quicktime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicktime) (for a tutorial I am making) on an iMac and the output was a .mov file.

I edited and deleted scenes with [openshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShot_Video_Editor) and know I don't now how to export it to a .mov file again.

I know the video format is supposed to be .mov but the codec I am not so sure about that h263, h262, libvpx?

Answer (score 0):

this web site http://www.h263l.com/ explains in great detail and depth. From my experience in usng Openshot using the drop down menu you can change your preferences and this web site will also answer in more detail http://www.openshotvideo.com/

Comment: i found a open-shot bug report(https://bugs.launchpad.net/openshot/+bug/901711) videoformaat= .mov video-codec=libx264 i tested it it worked for me it looked nice. i didn't record the audio so i don't no if the audio will work. in the bug report the audio codec used was. (Audio Codec: ac3
Sample Rate: 44100
No. of Channels: 2
Bit Rate : 128 kb/s) full video settings (Video Format: mov
Video Codec: libx264
Bit Rate: 5Mb/s)

Comment: audio didn't work :( still searching for the fix